# Transcender very slow

Tags: windows-7, installation, performance

I installed [Transcender](http://www.transcender.com/) to practice for a Microsoft certification. I also installed the exam question files. It is all very-very slow after a short while. Is there any way to help on this?

Further details:

- It's about 2-3 hours after the installation that [Transcender](http://www.transcender.com/) goes awfully slow (5-20 minutes waiting time at each mouse click).
- Tried on two very different laptops (HP vostro vs Sony VAIO) - installed overall 3 times on them - with the same result. Both laptops very strong (Office, Visual Studio, SQL Server, ...etc. nicely running on them) - and [Transcender](http://www.transcender.com/) runs on them in the first 2-3 hours after installation also very well. Conclusion: too weak hardware is not the problem.
- The installed exam in my certain case: 70-568 (MS)
- [Transcender](http://www.transcender.com/) Test Engine version: 3.7.8
- OS: Windows 7 Enterprise / Home

Comment: This is a reformatted question based on an already deleted [one](http://superuser.com/questions/99149/transcender-very-slow) where I first placed it *three weeks ago* as an addition. Since that I have made some further investigations on it - therefore, plz don't be surprised that now I'd also have a possible answer to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I've first placed this question (three weeks ago), I have made some further investigations and found a possible answer to it.

The problem was using special characters (like e.g. "á", "Á") in user profile when installing [Transcender](http://www.transcender.com/). It just brought some user specific XML files in [Transcender](http://www.transcender.com/)'s **ExamFiles** folder go totally out-of-control growing several MB large (in my case one of them more than 60 MB as I gave it up and re-installed the software). The larger these XMLs the slower [Transcender](http://www.transcender.com/) ran. I.e. this seems to be a **bug** in the [Transcender](http://www.transcender.com/) Test Engine.

**Workaround:**
After discovering this, I re-installed [Transcender](http://www.transcender.com/) without any uncommon character in user profile - about two weeks ago - and since that, it's running very well without any problem.

Comment: Please also remember to mark your answer as the correct solution when you can :)